# How to write a function that defines another function with given name

Tags: clojure

Here is my clojure code:

```
(defn salutation-adder-maker                                                                                   
  ([salutation call]                                                                                     
   (def call (salutation-adder-maker salutation)))                                                             
  ([salutation]                                                                                          
   #(str % salutation))                        
)                                                                                                        
(salutation-adder-maker "-Thanks!" salutation1)                                                              
(salutation1 "Help me!")
```

The bottom two lines of code give an error unable to resolve symbol `salutation1`. The function compiles fine, but this is because it defines the function as `call`. Thus the following code works:

```
(call "Help me!")
```

It spits out

```
Help me-Thanks!
```

Rather than the function `salutation1` having that functionality.  How can I change the code so that `salutation1` does the same thing as `call` is currently doing?

I want to be able to pass two arguments:

- the salutation to add at the end
- the name to give the function that adds that salutation

For example:

```
(salutation-adder-maker "-Have a good day!" day_salutation)
(day_salutation "I will talk to you later")=>"I will talk to you later-Have a good day!"
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide some example call and expected result. What do you mean by 'apply said salutation'?

Comment: Hopefully adding the desired output clarifies what I am aiming to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code seems to assume `def` works like a function. In spite of the syntax, it's very different, in particular the symbol you use as the first argument of def must be resolved at compile-time, not run-time. As a consequence, to build on top of `def`, you will tend to use a macro, not a function. This is problematic, because while the 2-args arity requires a macro, the 1-arg arity would be best served by a function.

Let me suggest to split the work into a function and a macro:

```
(defn salutation-maker [salutation]
  #(str % salutation))

(defmacro defsalutation [name salutation]
  `(def ~name (salutation-maker ~salutation)))
```

Comment: This works as I wanted!`'(defsalutation salut "-hello") (salut "tommy") => "tommy-hello"`